# Merge object properties without overwritting

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge

I know I should use Object.assign for this case but assign overwrite. I want to merge the common properties.

Here is the context :

I have this object array.

```
let myObjectArray = [
    { p1 : ["0000"], p2: "test", p3: "mamama" },
    { p1 : ["0100"], p2: "blabla", p3: "blablabla" },
    { p1 : ["0431"], p2: "test", p3: "mamama" }
]
```

Prop1 and prop3 have the same value of properties p2 and p3, only the p1 of both is different. I want to merge this array when p2 and p3 have the same value. Here is the result I want :

```
let resultArray = [
        { p1 : ["0000", "0431"], p2: "test", p3: "mamama" },
        { p1 : ["0100"], p2: "blabla", p3: "blablabla" },
    ]
```

I don't know how to do this : using assign()? or double loop to check common value but I should remove the occurence because of the double loop. Is there a better solution?

Comment: look into Array reduce - will perhaps make the code easier to manage

Comment: You may want to check your "object array" - it's not valid syntax - and neither is your expected result array

Comment: and lastly - understand that the number `0431` for example is decimal `281`, and `0100` is decimal `64`

Comment: please define *common* and why has `prop3` two properties with `p3`? what happens with `prop3` after *merging*?

Comment: oups, sorry, it was the morning. Correct that. Numbers were for the test, just imagine different string or number. It was just an example. I want to know how to do that to adapt to my project

Comment: @NinaScholz Common value in properties. Sorry just failed in typing

Comment: what is a common property? `p2` **and** `p3`?

Comment: Well, maybe I wasn't so clear. In the array the first and the third have the same p2 and p3 values but different p1. So, I want to merge it without overwritting p1 : just like in the example

Comment: @NinaScholz Not common properties. Common properties "value"!

Comment: @NinaScholz Look the first object have "test" for p2 and "mamama" for p3. The third have "test" for p2 and "mamama" for p3 too. Only the p1 is different. SO, I need to merge them and concat the p1 because it is different. I am cleared? If you have questions, don't hesitate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) as reference to the common values of the given keys and filter the array for existing objects.

```js
let array = [{ p1: ["0000"], p2: "test", p3: "mamama" }, { p1: ["0100"], p2: "blabla", p3: "blablabla" }, { p1: ["0431"], p2: "test", p3: "mamama" }];

array = array.filter((hash => o => {
    let key = ['p2', 'p3'].map(k => o[k]).join('|');
    if (!hash.has(key)) {
        hash.set(key, o);
        return true;
    }
    hash.get(key).p1.push(...o.p1);
})(new Map));
   
console.log(array);
```

With new objects as result, without mutating the given array.

```js
let array = [{ p1: ["0000"], p2: "test", p3: "mamama" }, { p1: ["0100"], p2: "blabla", p3: "blablabla" }, { p1: ["0431"], p2: "test", p3: "mamama" }],
    result = array.reduce((hash => (r, o) => {
        let key = ['p2', 'p3'].map(k => o[k]).join('|'),
            p = hash.get(key);
 
        if (!p) {
            p = Object.assign({}, o, { p1: [] });
            hash.set(key, p);
            r.push(p);
        }
        p.p1 = p.p1.concat(o.p1);
        return r;
    })(new Map), []);
   
console.log(result);
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Wow, thanks you very much. Hope it doesn't take you much time. I will check it later. Anyway, thanks a lot for your time

Comment: I have just one question for you. I don't really understand the notations of this part of your code : hash => (r, o) =>. I know the simple arrow function from ES6 but don't know about "=>" twice. If you can help me.

Comment: it is like `function (hash) { return function (r, o) {}; }(new Map)`. it is a closure over hash.